# Detect vuex state change to execute a method inside a nuxt layout

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js

I am trying to show vuetify snackbar alert, once I completed a form submission inside a page or vue component. I use vuex store to manage alert type and message.

**my-nuxt-app/store/alerts.js**

```
export const state = () => ({
    message: '',
    type: ''
});

export const getters = {

    hasAlert(state) {
        return state.message !== '';
    },

    alertMessage(state) {
        return state.message;
    },

    alertType(state) {
        return state.type;
    }
};

export const mutations = {

    SET_ALERT(state, payload) {
        state.type = payload.type;
        state.message = payload.message;
    }
};

export const actions = {

    setAlert({commit}, payload) {
        commit('SET_ALERT', payload);
    },
    clearAlert({commit}) {
        commit('SET_ALERT', {});
    }
};
```

And I created a nuxt plugin to access getters globally in my application.

**my-nuxt-app/plugins/alert.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';

const Alert = {
    install(Vue, options) {
        Vue.mixin({
            computed: {
                ...mapGetters({
                    hasAlert: 'alerts/hasAlert',
                    alertType: 'alerts/alertType',
                    alertMessage: 'alerts/alertMessage'
                })
            }
        });
    }
};

Vue.use(Alert);
```

Inside my `AccountForm` component submit method, I am dispatching my alert information to store like below.

**my-nuxt-app/components/form/AccountForm.vue**

```
...

methods: {
    async submit () {
        try {
            await this.$axios.patch("/settings/profile", this.form);
            this.$store.dispatch('alerts/setAlert', {
                type: 'success',
                message: 'You have successfully updated your information.'
            });
        } catch (e) {
        }
    }
},
...
}
...
```

And this `AccountForm.vue` component is a child component of `profile.vue` page which is obviously inside the *pages folder* of my project. And also I have extended the `dashboard.vue` layout to this `profile.vue` page and to the most of the pages inside my pages directory as a common layout. Hence, I added the snackbar component into `dashboard` layout to show a alert message whenever required.

**my-nuxt-app/layouts/dashboard.vue**

```
<template>
  ...

     <v-snackbar
            :timeout="snackbar.timeout"
            :color="snackbar.color"
            :top="snackbar.y === 'top'"
            :bottom="snackbar.y === 'bottom'"
            :right="snackbar.x === 'right'"
            :left="snackbar.x === 'left'"
            :multi-line="snackbar.mode === 'multi-line'"
            :vertical="snackbar.mode === 'vertical'"
            v-model="snackbar.show"
    >
      {{ snackbar.text }}
      <v-btn flat icon dark @click.native="snackbar.show = false">
        <v-icon>close</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-snackbar>

  ...
</template>

<script>

  ...

  data: () => ({
        snackbar: {
            show: false,
            y: 'top',
            x: null,
            mode: '',
            timeout: 6000,
            color: '',
            text: ''
        },
    }),
  computed: {
        availableAlert: function () {
            return this.hasAlert;
        }
    },
    watch: {
        availableAlert: function(alert) {
            if(alert) {
                this.showAlert(this.alertType, this.alertMessage);
                this.$store.dispatch('alerts/clearAlert');
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        showAlert(type, message) {
            this.snackbar.show = true;
            this.snackbar.color = type;
            this.snackbar.text = message;
        }
    }

</script>
```

I am getting the alert message for the first time submission of the form and after that I have to reload the page and then submit to get the alert. Please enlighten me a way to detect the vuex state change and trigger `showAlert` method inside the `dashboard.vue` accordingly.

Comment: making an example on codesandbox will be much easier than reading and trying to figure it out https://codesandbox.io/s/zqxk0lw813

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely the way you're checking `hasAlert`

Your `clearAlert` passes an empty object, your `setAlert` is trying to assign properties of that empty object, while your `hasAlert` is checking if it's an empty string.

If you change your clearAlert to:

```
clearAlert({commit}) {
    commit('SET_ALERT', { message: '', type: '' });
}
```

That should fix your issue.

Comment: Yes, it did fix the issue. What a silly mistake. :(